# Openmp safe way to open files

Tags: c, file, openmp

Let's say I have a parallelized program which runs many (parallelized) cycles, like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
   for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
   {
     for(int b=0;b<10;b++)
     {
       for(int c=0;c<10;c++)
       ....
```

And let's say that I want to put all the results in a File. A simple way to do so, may be this one:

```
FILE *fp1;
fp1=fopen("file.txt", "a");
#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(static, 1)
for(int a=0; a<10;a++)
{
 ...
  for(int c=0; c<10;c++)
  {
   ....
    #pragma omp ordered
    fprintf(fp1,"%f ", result);
   }
}//end of the parallelized section
fclose(fp1)
```

This way is a solution if the system doesn't have to keep in memory many variables, but it could be the case, plus I'd like to be "sure" that the file is written after every cycle.

Long story short I'd like to put an fclose and a fopen inside one of my internal loops, to be sure that even if (for some reason) the program aborts, at least something will be written in the output file.
Is there a way to do so?

Something like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
   for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
   {
     for(int b=0;b<10;b++)
     {
       FILE *fp1;
       fopen("file.txt", "a");
       for(int c=0;c<10;c++)
       {
        .... //part with fprintf
        } //c block
       fclose(fp1);
     }
    ....
   }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with openmp, but if indeed you will have many processes or threads running these loops in parallel, attempting to write to the same file at the same time from multiple threads of execution will invariably lead to sadness and doom.  And file corruption.  And if it's a threading solution, closing the file in one thread will close the file, period.

Comment: I was thinking something like a FILE pointer threadprivate, a  `#pragma omp single`  to open and close files with one thread, then putting other pointers to the file opened... and for the writing on the file, I know that you can use `#pragma omp ordered` directive to make thread enter in order into the block...

Comment: Why not keeping the file descriptor shared? Just use a `critical` section for blocks comprising of `fprintf()`s followed by a `fflush()`. This will make sure that whatever you wanted to be written on file has be written, even if the code crashes.

Comment: I second Gilles proposal. You will avoid the additional overhead of opening/closing the files.